# Inaccurate snapping in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm having trouble with inaccurate snapping in Illustrator CC 2014. Dragged anchor points snap a few pixels away from artboard edges. They also do this inconsistently, i.e., they are wrong in slightly different ways each time. The document has no guides or other objects.

Video of the problem: http://quick.as/7bkqswlo

**Settings turned OFF:**

- Align to pixel grid OFF
- Snap to Grid OFF
- Snap to Point OFF
- Smart Guides OFF
- Pixel Preview OFF
- All checkboxes in Preferences > Smart Guides unchecked

Comment: Is it possible that the snapping is lining up the bottom right corner of that rectangle? The video doesn't show the opposite corner. The only way to stop artboard snapping is to turn ON Smart Guides and turn OFF everything else.

Comment: Thanks, @Scott. The transformation is not affecting the bottom right corner of the rectangle; it's stationary. I have tried turning off everything except smart guides, and the object is still snapping to artboard edges.

Comment: Hi there! I'm migrating your question to superuser, I think they will be able to help you since this is not really a graphic design issue but a question about making the software work as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that you are working with the new Live Rectangle tool, right? In Adobe Illustrator 2014 new rectangles are always live rectangles. This is really cool tool but it has its huge limitation: the live rectangle cannot be properly aligned (pixel grid, smart guides) when resizing/scaling. The only option is to convert it into the paths (using Object > Shape > Expand Rectangle) and then align them to whatever you like.

Many users have noticed this strange behavior. Here are some trending discussions on the official Adobe Community Forum:

[Illustrator CC Align Problem](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1542418?sr=stream&ru=73060)

[Illustrator cc 2014 grid snap problem](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1504292?sr=stream&ru=2672778)

Answer (score -1):

This was a bug with smart shapes (which are default when drawing rectangle) and it is fixed in October update.